# addmargin, enumerate and align* miss an overfull hbox

Tags: lists, indentation, align, enumerate, warnings

The following document compiles as expected, and looks as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{addmargin}[1cm]{0mm}
        \lipsum[2]

        \begin{enumerate}
        \item
            \lipsum[3]

        \item
            \begin{align*}
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn
            \end{align*}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

The content of the `align*` environment overflows the normal text area. However, there is no "overfull hbox" warning. Making the text even longer eventually produces the warning, but it's too late - depending on the nesting, the warning only occurs if the text is shifted far out of the page.

How can I make sure to be warned in such situations?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the `align*` environment. If it is changed to `equation*`, a warning results. I've tried to locate the source of the problem, but the definition is very complicated, so no explanation yet.

Comment: `addmargin` is irrelevant; the missing warning doesn't depend on it.

Comment: @Dan does the proposed change below look OK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**

This has been fixed (using the code below) in release 2.17a of `amsmath` (August 2017).

---

`amsmath` explicitly tests for this situation and adds code to issue a warning

> `\begin{macro}{\black@}`
>
> This macro is made to produce an
>   overfull box message and possibly (depending on the value of
>   `\overfullrule`)  a rule in the margin if the total width of an
>   alignment   is larger than the value of `\displaywidth`.

Unfortunately the code it inserts only produces a warning with `fleqn` (flush left equations, which is the default for AMS classes) not with the centred 
equations which is the standard default.

The following fixes that, it should make no change at all in documents without over wide equations. For documents with over wide equations the internal box structure is slightly different but there should be no visible change to the document except in `draft` mode when as documented above, you get an overfull box rule at the margin.

This will probably appear in the next release of `amsmath` pending further testing.

As modified below the test file produces console output

```
Overfull \hbox (49.62772pt too wide) detected at line 38
```

Test file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\makeatletter
\def\black@#1{%
    \noalign{%
        \ifdim#1>\displaywidth
            \dimen@\prevdepth
            \nointerlineskip
            \vskip-\ht\strutbox@
            \vskip-\dp\strutbox@
            \vbox{\noindent\hbox to \displaywidth{\hbox to#1{\strut@\hfill}}}%
%       added this         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                         ^
            \prevdepth\dimen@
        \fi
    }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{addmargin}[1cm]{0mm}
        \lipsum[2]

        \begin{enumerate}
        \item
            \lipsum[3]

        \item
            \begin{align*}
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn
            \end{align*}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice to see this fixed – looking forward to seeing this in a future `amsmath` release!

Comment: @fefrei I just checked it in to our sources, so it will be in the next release, this week most likely.

Comment: but `fleqn` is *not* the default with ams document classes; the default is centered equations.  the code surrounding the `fleqn` definitions is convoluted and not well documented, but it is *not* the default.