# Align* inside enumerate goes out of margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, margins, enumerate

I am writing my thesis and have a lot of align* environments inside an enumerate environment. I have to use align* environment as I have huge math equations which are split over multiple lines. However often the text goes out of the margins without even showing a warning.  Why is this happening and how to avoid it? Here is an example

```
\documentclass[draft]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item  No warning
\begin{align*}
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblablahblahblahblahblahblahblablahblahblah
\end{align*}
\item But we see warning here
\begin{align*}
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblablahblahblahblahblahblahblablahblahblahblah
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}

and also here
\begin{align*}
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblablahblahblahblahblahblahblablahblahblahbl
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the  very latest version of amsmath you do get a warning from the first

```
Overfull \hbox (20.35115pt too wide) detected at line 11
```

triggered by

[addmargin, enumerate and align* miss an overfull hbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141287/addmargin-enumerate-and-align-miss-an-overfull-hbox)

Comment: Thanks! I am using texshop in mac. Do you know how to force texshop to use the latest version of amsmath?

Comment: texshop is just the editor, if you have texlive 2017 you should be able to update using tlmgr or I understand the mac has a front end called tex manager or some similar name (I don't have a mac:-)

Comment: Ok Thanks! I'll try to update otherwise I will just post the code at the start. Thanks so much!